# Unable to build example model neither under Linux nor under Windows with different errors

Tags: python, linux, windows, keras

I am trying to build a model from [Keras "first example"](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) with the following code:

```
from keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.contrib.keras.api.keras.layers import Dense, Input

# This returns a tensor
inputs = Input(shape=(784,))

# a layer instance is callable on a tensor, and returns a tensor
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)

# This creates a model that includes
# the Input layer and three Dense layers
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
```

No training no running, just building a model.

Under Linux (Ubuntu 14.04LTS, Python 3.5, Tensorflow 1.2.1, Keras 2.0.6) it complains

> TypeError: Input layers to a `Model` must be `InputLayer` objects.
>   Received inputs: Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 784), dtype=float32).
>   Input 0 (0-based) originates from layer type `InputLayer`.

Under Windows (Windows 10, Anaconda Python 3.5, Tensorflow-gpu 1.1.0, Keras 2.0.4) it complains

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_shape'

Are these bug, or obsolete documentation, or both, or what?

How to run this simple example from documentation site?

**UPDATE**

If I change first line to

```
 inputs = InputLayer(input_shape=(784,))
```

then both operating systems start to complain:

```
 AttributeError: 'InputLayer' object has no attribute 'get_shape'
```

Comment: Why are you mixing keras Model with layers imported from tensorflow module?

Comment: @Harwee good question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input

# This returns a tensor
inputs = Input(shape=(784,))

# a layer instance is callable on a tensor, and returns a tensor
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)

# This creates a model that includes
# the Input layer and three Dense layers
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)

model.summary()
```

Don't mix the Keras standalone module with the one in contrib.